# Is the counting version of 1-in-3 Sat #P-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, counting-complexity

In the paper "[Hard Tiling Problems with Simple Tiles](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00454-001-0047-6)", Moore and Robson prove that Cubic Planar Positive 1-in-3 Sat in NP-complete by a reduction from Positive 1-in-3 Sat.

**Cubic Planar Positive 1-in-3 Satisfiability**
*Instance*: A boolean formula $B=(X,C)$ where $X$ is a set of variables, $C$ a set of 3-element subsets over $X$ (clauses), and graph of B is a cubic planar graph.
*Question*: Does there exist a truth assignment for $X$ such that each clause is $C$ has exactly one true variable?

(see the note of the https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/42605/47855 regarding terminology)

Then they prove that a particular tiling problem is NP-complete by a reduction from Cubic Planar Positive 1-in-3 Sat. 
The following note is given after their reduction:

> While the reduction from this version of SAT to the tiling problem we gave in the previous section is parsimonious, this does not show that the counting problem is #P-complete, since we do not have such a result for Cubic Planar Positive 1-in-3 SAT. We leave this as an open problem for the reader.

This gave me the impression that the counting version of 1-in-3 Sat is indeed #P-complete, but I couldn't find any source claiming this. **Is the counting version of 1-in-3 Sat #P-complete?**

Comment: No, it is NP-complete. Do you mean its counting counterpart? Anyway, there is a reference right in the question that you linked to: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540196900164 .

Comment: @Gamow, I don't understand why you remove the alternate names of the problem 1-in-3 Sat from the title. Many authors use the names Exactly one 3-sat and XSAT. If you are so sure it doesn't belong in the title, please consider adding these alternate names in the body of the question.

Comment: @EmilJeřábeksupportsMonica  You are welcome to expand your comment into an answer. (I shall remove my answer after that.) I didn't realise that i forgot to explicitly state that it is the counting version i am talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the counting version of 1-in-3 Sat is $\#P$-complete. This is stated in "Complexity of Generalized Satisfiability Counting Problems" (Example 3.1), the reference pointed out by Emil in the comment.

Note:
This leads us to the curious question: is the counting version of every NP-complete problem $\#P$-complete? The answers to this question ([When does "X is NP-complete" imply "#X is #P-complete"?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/16119/47855)) suggest so!

Comment: Shall I make this ans community wiki, or not?